# shopt works in command line, not found when run in a script

Tags: bash, scripts

I'm writing a script to copy some files around, and trying to use `shopt -s dotglob` [to enable cp to copy dotfiles](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-software-2/cp-command-cant-do-dotfiles-308492/) like `.jshint` and whatnot.

I can run `shopt -s dotglob` directly at a bash prompt with no error.  However, running the script throws the error:

```
script.sh: 81: script.sh: shopt: not found
```

I'm running this script in bash shell, with the shebang header `#!/usr/bin/env bash`.  Error line:

```
shopt -s dotglob
cp -r $TEMP/img/* $TARGET/img/
cp -r $TEMP/js/* $TARGET/js/
cp -r $TEMP/less/* $TARGET/less/
```

Not finding anything helpful on google, any idea what the problem is here?

Comment: Thanks for the reminder, selected answers for all that I could.  Still one besides this question that doesn't have a good answer yet.

Comment: Try with the simpler `#!/bin/bash` header?

Comment: And which Ubuntu version?

Comment: @izx, that is the right answer, `shopt` is a bash builtin, `sh` does not have `shopt`, and the error message looks like an error message from `dash`. So most likely the error here is running a bash script with `sh` (which in Ubuntu is `dash` by default). Even if `sh` is a symlink to `bash`, running a bash script with `sh` is not the same as running it with `bash`.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To form an answer from the comments:

Many people out of habit run their scripts with `sh` instead of `bash`. This is a good practice if portability is a concern, but many people do so because they're copying something they've seen without understanding it.

Unless your script needs to run on a non-desktop Linux system (e.g., running shell scripts on Android devices is quite different), I recommend using the Bash shebang line at the beginning:

```
#!/bin/bash
```

This line, when it's the first line in the script, determines which interpreter (shell such as bash or sh, Python, etc.) is called to execute it. If you use the above line, you'll get the same behavior (almost) as you do from the command line, assuming you use the default shell. If for reasons of portability or preference you use a different shebang line, be aware that you'll have to consult the documentation for the shell you've referenced, *even if* the shell you reference is a symlink to Bash.

Comment: To be completely cross-system, I prefer:

`#!/usr/bin/env bash`

as it is env's job to know which bash to use (in case you've patched it, for example).

Comment: Exactly what I looking for. Thx :)

Comment: Just adding in something here for the newbies or those (like me) that constantly get slapped in the face by minutiae errors... "#!/bin/bash" really does need to be on the first line. My script somehow got a newline put in for line one so the shell declaration was on line 2. I've been punching dirt for two days trying to figure out why my perfectly fine script suddenly stopped working.

Answer (score 3):

You need to exit zsh and activate bash as shown:

```
exec bash
```

The run the command

```
source ~/.bashrc
```

After which you can reactive zsh:

```
exec zsh
```

Hope that helps

Comment: Hmmm. 1) I don't think the OP was using zsh, 2) AFAIK `~/.basrc` is run by bash on startup in this case so there is no need to call it explicitly, 3) where is the OP's command executed? and 4) using `exec` twice makes you lose any environment changes you have done in the initial zsh shell, which wouldn't happen if you would just call bash.

Comment: In my case, it was needed to pick up environment changes and the changes did persist. I just restarted the computer and all my changes are persisted. Maybe it is just specific to anaconda which I was trying to setup though

Comment: i am not sure why this answer is down voted, this is also one of the way, upvoting

Comment: the problem is some command is only exist in the bash environment if you usually use linux command