# How to use shopt command in upstart configuration file?

Tags: bash, scripts, upstart

I am trying to create an upstart configuration file where inside the script section I am using shopt command to set the nullglob paramater -

```
shopt -s nullglob
```

However, with this I am getting the following error -

```
/proc/self/fd/9: 8: /proc/self/fd/9: shopt: not found
```

Can we use shopt inside an upstart script, has anyone used this before? Also, since shopt is a builtin command I couldn't find the exact path that I can include in my script to execute shopt from there. Any pointers would be extremely appreciated.

FYI -  I am working on Ubuntu.

I am able to use shopt from command line and from a shell script. However only while using it inside the upstart configuration file I am having this issue.

Thanks!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [shopt works in command line, not found when run in a script](http://askubuntu.com/questions/180873/shopt-works-in-command-line-not-found-when-run-in-a-script)

Comment: See also https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/pm-utils/+bug/1190869

Comment: shopt works fine for me when I use it in a normal shell script - so certainly its not a duplicate of that question.

Comment: Also I cannot remove it as I am using it to check if a file matches a particular pattern or not.

Comment: what is a "normal script" exactly ? You can script with bash, dash, perl, python, etc. Post your script.

Comment: `shopt` is a bash builtin not an external program. AFAIK `upstart` uses `/bin/sh`, which is symlinked to `dash` on Ubuntu - and `dash` doesn't have an equivalent of `shopt`. So you will need to implement a different (POSIX?) strategy to do your test (maybe using `expr`?)

Comment: can you post your script?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the comments it helped me troubleshoot the actual issue. 
As steeldriver mentioned `shopt` is a `bash` builtin and since`upstart` uses `/bin/sh` by default and it is symlinked to `dash`, therefore `shopt` wasn't working.

Also the script in which `shopt` worked was a bash script (hope it answers bodho.zazen's question).

After some research what I did was enclose my `shopt` command like this in the script section, and this worked -

```
script 

/bin/bash <<'EOF'
  <my-code>
  shopt -s nullglob
  <my-code>
EOF

end script
```

Thanks to all of you for helping me out! :)